# Converting from svg into pdf preserving image metadata

Tags: image, pdf, svg, metadata, inkscape

I have `.svg` files with metadata information, e.g., `creator`, `contributor`, `licence`, and so on. Now, when I convert them into `.pdf` I loose all these metadata and I see only `cairo 1.14.6 (http://cairographics.org)` as *Producer* and *Creator*.

For conversion, I have tried both [cairosvg 2.4.2 and inkscape 0.92.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828182/imagemagick-svg-to-pdf-conversion-image-quality-is-bad/64007916#55076653). And all the `.svg` metadata is lost. :\

I have two questions:

- Is there any method or application to convert `.svg` into `.pdf` and preserve the metadata?
- Or, alternatively, after converting, could I somehow transfer the metadata from `.svg` into `.pdf` easily?

Thanks.

PS: Surprisingly, when I use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/) to transform from `.svg` to `.png` the metadata is preserved.

Comment: As for Inkscape's limitations, see https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#PDF_Export

Comment: @Moini Oh, thanks!, it seems that inkscape version `1.00` exports already some metadata into the .pdf, but I am using version `0.92.5`. That's sad.

Comment: You could update... unless you depend on extensions that haven't been updated yet.

Comment: That's the deal on ubuntu 16.04. Another reason to move into 18.04. ;)

Comment: Use the AppImage :)

Comment: That was a good idea! Thanks again, I found that inkscape is installable through [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.inkscape.Inkscape)

Comment: Yep, that's another option, esp. if you're already using flatpak (or snap, if you want that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new Inkscape **version `1.01`**, most part of the metadata is preserved when converting from `.svg` to `.pdf`, while in the previous version, `0.92.5`, it was lost.

Thanks to @Moini for giving a hint in the release notes of Inkscape.

**For Linux:**
Install the newest Inkscape [version 1.01 using flatpak](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/gnulinux/flatpak/dl/)